# Getting the center of a feature collection in GeoJSON?

Tags: postgis, geojson, google-maps, google-maps-api, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a project where I make a call to my API to get back GeoJSON for a 3 mile radius from a given address. It returns back towns for me in a feature collection by using PostGIS/Tiger. The data comes back correct and works.

I then load this data into Google Maps like so:

```
 map.data.addGeoJson(data);
```

Is there a way to now take the geojson that is loaded, and center in on that point?

I have a feature collection of polygons for an address in a 5 mile radius. I was hoping I could just get the center without having to update my SQL query and return it from the API.

Comment: do you mean `loadGeoJson`? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#load_geojson

Comment: What about using the point your using for your 3 mile radius? Isn't that waht you really want to center the view on? Then just use map.setCenter({lat:LAT_VALUE, lng:LONG_VALUE});

Comment: @BillChappell I'm taking an address the user types in, and then geocoding it to an area of GeoJSON. The response I get back is GeoJSON so I have to either parse that, or have my response include two things now (GeoJSON, and a long/lat to center in on which would have to be done on the database side). I don't mind doing it, but was hoping that there was a client-side way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you may use js library, turfjs can do that. Take a look at http://turfjs.org/docs/#center . It is stated that "Takes a Featureor FeatureCollectionand returns the absolute center point of all features." You may zoom to returned point.